# GDAL Python JPEG2000 read error on Windows

Tags: python, gdal, jpeg-2000

I recently went back to Windows from Linux to find out that GDAL returns the following error when trying to open Sentinel-2 JPEG2000 files:

> not recognized as a supported file format

The odd thing is that it has no problem opening the same file on Linux and it has no problem opening GeoTIFF files on Windows.
On both platforms, I'm using an virtual environment created with Anaconda 3 containig the following modules:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl
absl-py                   0.7.1                    py36_0
astor                     0.8.0                    py36_0
astroid                   2.2.5                    py36_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0
certifi                   2019.6.16                py36_1
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0
colorama                  0.4.1                    py36_0
curl                      7.65.2               h2a8f88b_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
cytoolz                   0.10.0           py36he774522_0
dask-core                 2.2.0                      py_0
decorator                 4.4.0                    py36_1
expat                     2.2.5                he025d50_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
freexl                    1.0.5                hfa6e2cd_0
gast                      0.2.2                    py36_0
gdal                      2.3.3            py36hdf43c64_0
geos                      3.7.1                h33f27b4_0
grpcio                    1.16.1           py36h351948d_1
h5py                      2.9.0            py36h5e291fa_0
hdf4                      4.2.13               h712560f_2
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
imageio                   2.5.0                    py36_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
isort                     4.3.21                   py36_0
joblib                    0.13.2                   py36_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
kealib                    1.4.7                h07cbb95_6
keras                     2.2.4                         0
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-base                2.2.4                    py36_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py36ha925a31_0
krb5                      1.16.1               hc04afaa_7
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.1            py36he774522_0
libboost                  1.67.0               hd9e427e_4
libcurl                   7.65.2               h2a8f88b_0
libgdal                   2.3.3                h10f50ba_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libkml                    1.3.0                he5f2a48_4
libmklml                  2019.0.5                      0
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h411e497_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libpq                     11.2                 h3235a2c_0
libprotobuf               3.8.0                h7bd577a_0
libspatialite             4.3.0a              hc36aec2_19
libssh2                   1.8.2                h7a1dbc1_0
libtiff                   4.0.10               hb898794_2
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
markdown                  3.1.1                    py36_0
matplotlib                3.1.0            py36hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.0.2            py36he774522_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.12           py36h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py36h343c172_0
mock                      3.0.5                    py36_0
networkx                  2.3                        py_0
numpy                     1.16.4           py36h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.16.4           py36hc3f5095_0
olefile                   0.46                     py36_0
openssl                   1.1.1c               he774522_1
pandas                    0.25.0           py36ha925a31_0
pcre                      8.43                 ha925a31_0
pillow                    6.1.0            py36hdc69c19_0
pip                       19.1.1                   py36_0
proj4                     5.2.0                ha925a31_1
protobuf                  3.8.0            py36h33f27b4_0
pylint                    2.3.1                    py36_0
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py36_1
python                    3.6.9                h5500b2f_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py36_0
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0
pywavelets                1.0.3            py36h8c2d366_1
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py36he774522_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
scikit-image              0.15.0           py36ha925a31_0
scikit-learn              0.21.2           py36h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.3.0            py36h29ff71c_0
setuptools                41.0.1                   py36_0
sip                       4.19.8           py36h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py36_0
sqlite                    3.29.0               he774522_0
tensorboard               1.13.1           py36h33f27b4_0
tensorflow                1.13.1          mkl_py36hd212fbe_0
tensorflow-base           1.13.1          mkl_py36hcaf7020_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                     py_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py36he774522_0
typed-ast                 1.3.4            py36he774522_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
werkzeug                  0.15.4                     py_0
wheel                     0.33.4                   py36_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
wrapt                     1.11.2           py36he774522_0
xerces-c                  3.2.2                ha925a31_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

I remember that it used to work on Windows a couple of months ago. So I tried also on a fresh install without any other software but the result is the same.

Before trying to read, i set my "GDAL_DATA" enviroment variable to:

```
os.environ["GDAL_DATA"]='C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\RS\\Library\\share\\gdal'
```

I also tried to manually install openjpeg using conda, without any luck.

Comment: Create a new env and install gdal, but this time specify the conda-forge channel (i.e. `conda create -n yourenv -c conda-forge gdal and your other packages`).  The default anaconda gdal install is useless, doesn't support BigTIFF and sounds like it doesn't support OpenJPEG either...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also tried that but it did help me. I actually just found out that to fix it on windows it's enought to force-install gdal=2.2.2 . Before closing i need to check if this is also necessary on linux or if it's just a windows issue.

Comment: Did you check if your other GDAL version was compiled with any JPEG2000 driver `gdalinfo --formats`?